# Mysql MATCH AGAINST short words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match-against

I want to display relevant products on a page. I use the following query:

```
SELECT item.*, MATCH (item.title) AGAINST ('M' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevancy 
FROM __items AS item 
ORDER BY relevancy DESC
```

The table __items has a few items (id, title) and one with title just M.

I tried using an asterisk `('M*')`, but it didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You should decrease MySQL parameter `ft_min_word_length=1` on your my.cnf.

Comment: should that not be `ft_min_word_len=1` ? ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer because it is different; `ft_min_word_length` relates to MYISAM tables but its different for InnoDB:

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by
>   the innodb_ft_min_token_size and innodb_ft_max_token_size for InnoDB
>   search indexes, and ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len for MyISAM
>   ones.

This is based on the revised manual link of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html (v8 of MySQL)